# Python: appending two regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have two regular expressions (alternatively, their pattern strings) and I would like to concatenate them.

That is given `re1` and `re2`, I would like to construct `re3`, where `re3` matches S iff `re1` matches some prefix of S, and then `re2` matches the remainder.

Some bad ideas:

1. Match `re1` and then `re2` on the remainder. This fails for example for `/x*/ + /x/` on the string "xxx" since the greedy match consumes the last x.
2. Append the patterns. This fails for example on `/a|b/` + `/c/` since that produces `/a|bc/`, and `|` has lower precedence than catenation.

Some better ideas:

1. Append the patterns inside non-capturing groups. This solve the precedence problem; however it mishandles back references. This is currently my least bad idea.
2. "Manually backtrack" by enumerating *all* of the ways that `re1` can match S, followed by `re2` on the remainder after the match. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any support for this in Python.

Any better approaches? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean in the first "bad" idea; `x*x` matches `xxx`. It fails on the *first* attempt, since `x*` indeed matches everything and there is nothing left for the trailing `x` to match, but the RE engine then backtracks and tries matching again, being "less greedy" with `x*`.

Comment: Yes, regular expressions are just strings, so you just concatenate them with `+`. (`x*x` isn't as *efficient* as `xx*` would be, but that's a different problem.)

Comment: The first bad idea is to match with re1, and then re2. That fails for `'x*'` and `'x'` matching "xxx". The second bad idea is to match re1 + re2, which fails for `'a|b'` and `'c'` matching "ac".

Comment: The first one does *not* fail; the second just requires explicit parenthesization because concatenation has higher precedence than `|`.

Comment: Yeah wrapping each pattern in a non-capturing group and then appending them is my current best idea; the main flaw is that it mishandles back references.

Comment: What do you mean by "mishandles back references"?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish - Instead of using numbered back references which break on appending, you could try named ones which may be less likely to collide depending on how much control you have of the regex parts you're combining: https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions concatenate; in fact, it's one of the basic rules for construction more complicated regular expressions from the basics. However, doing so may require explicit parenthesization.

```
re1 = 'x*'
re2 = 'x'
# This works because 'x*x' and '(x*)x' are equivalent regular expressions
if re.match(re1 + re2, 'xxx'):
    print("Success!")

re1 = 'a|b'
re2 = 'c'
# Here, you need the parentheses because 'a|bc' and '(a|b)c' are not equivalent.
# "Parentheses" here means a non-capturing group.
if re.match("(?:%s)%s" % (re1, re2), "ac"):
    print("Success!")
```

Comment: Why not just capture both `re1` and `re2` groups then? But I would assume that causes another problem if one of those have a capturing group inside.  My original thought would be to have `f'({re1})(*)({re2})'`, at which point you can just look for group 0 and group 2.

Comment: the OP already talked about concatenating (also with non-capturing groups, which is better), but said the problem was with backreferences

Comment: I switched to a non-capturing group, which is what parenetheses mean in "real" regular expressions. (Python regular expressions have lots of features, including capture groups, that make them strictly more power than actual regular expressions.)

Comment: in all languages I know, groups are capturing by default

Comment: And every language you know implements something that is a superset of regular expressions as they were originally defined (as a simple representation of a finite automaton).

Comment: This almost works except for backreferences. For example append `(.)\1` (matches 'aa', 'bb', etc) to itself, you get `(.)\1(.)\1` (matches 'aaba'; what you instead want is `(.)\1(.)\2` ('aabb')

Comment: OK, *that's* a bit tricky to work around. It's somewhat like the problem of formally defining beta reduction on lambda calculus, because you have to account for name collisions in the variables used. (Note that back references are one of the things that make Python's regular expressions not *really* regular expressions; they allow you to match strings that even a context-free grammar cannot match, but at the same time Python regexes cannot match some languages that CFGs can.)

Comment: Basically, you have to figure out how many captures groups are in `re1`, then *add* that number to each backreference in `re2`. Then, given `re1` and your modified `re2` (call it `re2a`), you can use `'(?:%s)%s' % (re1, re2a)`. Unless you already know how many captures groups are in `re1`, determine how many there are is probably worthy of a question by itself.

Comment: (Update: it's actually easy to find out how many capture groups there are; compile the regular expression and examine the `groups` attribute of the resulting object. Modifying the second regular expression to update any back references is still a bit tricky, requiring you to parse the regular expression and rebuild it. There are also name collisions to worry about if both expressions use `(?P...)` groups.)